# Read string custom with whitespace check

Tags: c#, string, parsing, substring, console-application

Hello I am using Console Application and I am reading string and get my values:

String :

```
 Information                                                                                                                        
First Name: WORLD    Middle: HELLO Last Name: PQRS
 
CalBRE: 012345678 Login ID: IVACOSEST
Address: 12345 ABCd RD.
 
City: ABCd XYZ State: California Zip: 12345                                                           
Direct Office Ph: 123-456-7890 Cell Phone: 123-456-7890
Home Phone: Fax: 123-456-7890
Toll Free Phone: Pager:
Voicemail:
Email: abcd@abcd.net
Office Information                                                                                                                                                   
Office Name: Offc. Office Code: IVNEXT
Address: 165 ABC XYZ LANE #10 Office CalBRE: 0123456
City: San Fransisco Zip: 12345
Phone: 123-456-7890 Fax: 123-456-7890
```

From my above string I want to read the data like below:

FirstName

Middle

LastName

DirectOffice

I want to read the data as FirstName and than from first name starting until it gets white space please suggest me anyone how I do?

I have just done following code:

```
var stIndex = String[i].IndexOf("FirstName") + (FirstName).Length;
```

String has thousand of records so I have put loop each array has String as I have provided above example.

In above sample code I get the starting point but how to get last point:

I mean example I want to read FirstName so I got starting point of First Name but how to read First Name: Value i.e. WORLD until comes to white space!

Answer (score 0):

How about you read all characters between First Name: and Middle: then trim the resulting string to get the value of first name,.

```
int startIndex = String[i].IndexOf("First Name") + ("First Name:").Length;
int middleNameStartIndex = String[i].IndexOf("Middle");

string FirstNameValue = String[i].Substring(startIndex, middleNameStartIndex - startIndex).trim();
```

similar for all others, you know the placement of keys so you can perform similar operation for all others...

Comment: Thanks for reply but I have used that logic but in case when I don't have middle name what should I do it gives me different value and sometime error. So for that reason I want to read from the starting point of string like FirstName upto end.

Comment: @padhiyar You can have string array with all key names, then you can loop through it to find minimum length index, once you find minimum length index you will be sure that it is going to be your next key, then read characters between base key and the one you just found from array with minimum length

Comment: @padhiyar let me know if you want a sudo-code for it.... I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I defined an array every list item searched inside the string as following,

```
string a = "your text";
List<string> results = new List<string>();
string[] searchList = { "First Name:", "Middle:", "Last Name:", "Direct Office Ph:" };

foreach (var item in searchList)
        {
            int indexStarts = a.IndexOf(item); // first whitespace
            a = a.Substring(indexStarts + item.Length + 1);
            if (a.Substring(a.IndexOf(" "), a.IndexOf(" ")).Trim() == "-") // in the phone seperator we need to approach another solution so checking - character
            {
                string result = "";
                while (a.Substring(a.IndexOf(" "), a.IndexOf(" ")).Trim() == "-")
                { // if the following string between whitespaces has - we need to loop
                    result += a.Substring(0, a.IndexOf(" ") + 3); //white space - whitespace so 3 character it will generate 123 - then 456 - ..
                    a = a.Substring(a.IndexOf(a.Substring(0, a.IndexOf(" ") + 3)) + a.Substring(0, a.IndexOf(" ") + 3).Length); 
// after taking numbers 123 -, 456 - it will reproduce the text and making start a new startpoint before - and whitespaces

                }
                result += a.Substring(0, a.IndexOf(" ") + 1); // if while loop ends it means there is one whitespace at the 7890 Cell Phone: behind 0 and C so we need to substring it.
                results.Add(item + " " + result); // add to list
            }
            else
            {
                results.Add(item + " " + a.Substring(0, a.IndexOf(" ") + 1)); // this one add directly (for firstname,middle,lastname)
            }

        }
```

Here is the result (btw it is only for one string, just for the logic),

[image]

Hope helps,

Answer (score 0):

I would start with code like below.  You input is very tricky to parse and requires a custom parser.  It is tricky for following reasons
1) Multiple properties on one line
2) Property Names being multiple words with spaces in between
3) Value being multiple words with spaces in between
4) Some properties have no values

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            string inputLine = "";
            Person newPerson = null;
            while((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null);
            {
                inputLine = inputLine.Trim();
                if (inputLine.Length > 0)
                {
                    if (inputLine.Contains("Information"))
                    {
                        newPerson = new Person();
                        Person.peopel.Add(newPerson);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //enter code to parse data
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public class Person
    {
        public static List<Person> peopel = new List<Person>();
        public Dictionary<string, string> properties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }
}
```